# XCode Preprocessor Macro for Configuration?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I want my XCode Objective-C project to be able to detect which configuration it is being built with. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have per-configuration macro definitions.  Open up your project settings, select your configuration from the **Configuration** drop-down menu, and go to **Preprocessor Macros**.  For Debug, I recommend defining the macro `_DEBUG`, and for release I recommend defining `_RELEASE`, as these are the typical ones which are used.  These are passed on to the compiler as `-D` options, e.g. `-D_DEBUG`.

You can also put `-D` options directly into the **Other C Flags** setting.

Comment: Can I define them under "User-Defined" because I don't see "Preprocessor Macros" unless you mean "Info.plist other preprocessor flags"?

Comment: It seems that if I selected "Base SDK" the options would then appear.

Comment: @Adam - `_DEBUG` and `_RELEASE` are OK, but non-standard. Posix only observes `NDEBUG`, so the Release configuration should definitely include it. To cover all the bases (including interop'ing with other libraries, such as SQLite and SQLCipher), and including your macros: Debug configurations should have the following preprocessor macros: `_DEBUG`, `DEBUG=1`; and Release configuration should have `_RELEASE`, `NDEBUG=1`, `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1` preprocessor macros.